# ng-repeat except value 2

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data.arrayElement">
    <strong>{{element.name}}</strong>
</div>
```

The previuos collection have 5 elements. Can i iterate the collection except the element that has the value 2?. I don't know, maybe like this

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data.arrayElement | filter:element.val() !== 2">
    <strong>{{element.name}}</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that would work (you would need to set up a real filter to do that though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ngIf` because the 
`ngIf` differs from `ngShow` and `ngHide` in that `ngIf` completely removes and recreates the element in the `DOM` rather than changing its visibility via the display `css` property.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data.arrayElement" ng-if="element.val !== 2">
```

Comment: Cool! Works fine. Thank everyone for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `ng-hide` on that value:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data.arrayElement" ng-hide="element.val == 2">
```

Answer (score 0):

collect

```
$scope.data = [
  {name:'John', value:'1'},
  {name:'Mike', value:'2'},
  {name:'Alex', value:'3'}
  ];
```

html

```
 <div ng-repeat="element in data | filter:{value:'!2'}">
  <strong>{{element.name}}</strong>
</div>
```